# When Im using SELECT * FROM sample, How Can I Put it on TOP

Tags: php

example

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sample");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

echo 'Hello, '.$row['name'].'.<br>';
}

Hello, sample.
Hello, sample1.
Hello, sample2.
```

I want that the sample2 Go to TOP. ^

```
Hello, sample2.
Hello, sample1.
Hello, sample.
```

Comment: Check out `ORDER BY` in mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM sample ORDER BY [field name] ASC/DESC (ascending/descending)";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello May I ask, how you do that? background color. Sorry I'm Newbie here :)

Comment: You mean the grey container that contains the code? Type <pre>//your code here</pre>

Comment: Oh... Many Thanks :) .. <pre>How can I give you Reputation?</pre> . :)?

Comment: pre only works when you're submitting an answer. You can't because you have not reached 15 reps :(

Comment: @janmichaelmallari Click `edit` below your question and see how it looks now; the code is indented with 4 spaces (there is a button for that...).

Comment: You can also use the keyboard shortcut CTRL + K

Comment: Guys Guys... How Can I have **REPUTATION**?

Answer (score 1):

you can use order by clause.. this is the syntax

```
SELECT * FROM sample order by name desc
```

Comment: May I Use. 'SELECT * FROM sample **WHERE ref='KEL'** ORDER BY name desc?

Comment: '$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stockman_paris WHERE type='Mannequin' ORDER BY id");' Its not working

Comment: what's happening in your code? not returning any result?